# Extra Spaces in ng-autocomplete

Tags: angular, angular-material, autocomplete

I was using ng-autocomplete for my property search feature so the requirement is to search the property name by entered text, but then I found out some property name where seperated by spaces like "maverick property"(actual name) is replaced by "Mav Erick Property" which is not desirable in some situations.

I guess behind the scenes ng-autocomplete uses "Named Entity Recognition" . So It would be better to provide option to disable that feature in certain scenario.

Please let me know if any feature available.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. However it seems like you are not familiar with the guide of Stack Overflow to [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please read it and adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option. Happy coding!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the custom filter provided by Angular autocomplete
More information available here:
[Angular ng autocomplete inputs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-ng-autocomplete)

> customFilter -> Custom filter function. You can use it to provide your own filtering function, as e.g. fuzzy-matching filtering, or to disable filtering at all (just pass (items) => items as a filter). Do not change the items argument given, return filtered list instead.

You can also checkout this example of custom filters and remove the space from the input value entered and the 'names' in your data array:
[Custom filter example](https://github.com/gmerabishvili/angular-ng-autocomplete/tree/master/src/app/home)

.html file-

```
<div class="ng-autocomplete">
    <ng-autocomplete
        [data]="names"
        [searchKeyword]="keyword"
        [customFilter]="customFilter"
        [placeholder]="placeholder"
        [itemTemplate]="itemTemplateStatic"
        [notFoundTemplate]="notFoundTemplate">
    </ng-autocomplete>

    <ng-template #itemTemplateStatic let-item>
        <a [innerHTML]="item.name"></a>
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template #notFoundTemplate let-notFound>
        <div [innerHTML]="notFound"></div>
    </ng-template>
</div>
```

.ts file:

```
customFilter(items: any, query: string) {
    return items.filter((item: any) => {
        return item.name.replace(/\s/g, '').toLowerCase().indexOf(query.replace(/\s/g, '').toLowerCase()) > -1;
    });
}
```